# Testing iOS Share Extensions with Apple Wallet

Tags: ios-extensions, ios8-share-extension, wallet

I would like to test if my share extension works with the Share option available inside the passes from Apple Wallet. I have already tried to run the extension from Xcode, I can find some apps (Messages, Maps, Safari, etc...) but I can't find Wallet. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: use passkit framework

Comment: @nicola-giancecchi did you ever solve this?

Comment: I'm interested in how you got this to work also?